# How can I combine these 3 different queries into one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 queries in a MySQL database that output all the same fields except the last one, which is a calculation. I would like, if possible, to combine them into one query that outputs the common fields plus the additional calculated fields.

These are the queries:

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT 
    accesslogs.login, 
    usuarios.login, 
    usuarios.nombre, 
    usuarios.apellido, 
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    accesslogs 
    LEFT JOIN usuarios ON accesslogs.login = usuarios.id_usuario
WHERE
    accesslogs.id_campania=173 
    AND accesslogs.tipo_acceso='A' 
    AND usuarios.id_usuario != 6658
GROUP BY accesslogs.login 
ORDER BY usuarios.login ASC
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT 
    accesslogs.login, 
    usuarios.login, 
    usuarios.nombre, 
    usuarios.apellido, 
    MIN(accesslogs.fecha_registro) 
FROM 
    accesslogs 
    LEFT JOIN usuarios ON accesslogs.login = usuarios.id_usuario
WHERE 
    accesslogs.id_campania=173 
    AND accesslogs.tipo_acceso='A' 
    AND usuarios.id_usuario != 6658
GROUP BY accesslogs.login 
ORDER BY usuarios.login ASC
```

**Query 3:**

```
SELECT 
    accesslogs.login, 
    usuarios.login, 
    usuarios.nombre, 
    usuarios.apellido, 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    accesslogs 
    LEFT JOIN usuarios ON accesslogs.login = usuarios.id_usuario
WHERE 
    accesslogs.id_campania=173 
    AND accesslogs.tipo_acceso='U' 
    AND usuarios.id_usuario != 6658
GROUP BY accesslogs.login 
ORDER BY usuarios.login ASC
```

You can notice that the first 4 fields in the `SELECT` are always the same. The output I'm looking for is something like:

```
Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | Field 4 | CF Query 1 | CF Query 2 | CF Query 3
```

*CF: calculated field, last field in the SELECT of the corresponding query*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should get the job done. I changed the `WHERE` condition on `tipo_acceso` to a `IN` clause and used conditional aggreation to compute the counts and the min.

```
SELECT 
    a.login, 
    u.login, 
    u.nombre, 
    u.apellido, 
    SUM(a.tipo_acceso = 'A') cnt_A,
    MIN(CASE WHEN a.tipo_acceso = 'A' THEN a.fecha_registro END) min_fecha_registro,
    SUM(a.tipo_acceso = 'U') cnt_U
FROM 
    accesslogs a
    LEFT JOIN usuarios u ON a.login = u.id_usuario
WHERE 
    a.id_campania = 173 
    AND a.tipo_acceso IN ('A', 'U')
    AND u.id_usuario != 6658
GROUP BY 
    a.login, 
    u.login, 
    u.nombre, 
    u.apellido 
ORDER BY 
    u.login ASC
```

Other notable points:

- all non-aggregated columns must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause; on any RDBMS other than old versions of MySQL, failing to comply with this rule generates a fatal error
- I used table aliases to shorten the query

Comment: MIN(a.fecha_registro)  should be conditional , 'A' only according to OP's Query 2

Comment: @Serg: you are right, I missed that. Query updated, thanks for spotting this!

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Just one question, trying to understand what everything does, but this part I don't fully get it: `MIN(CASE WHEN .tipo_acceso = 'A' THEN a.fecha_registro END) min_fecha_registro,`

Comment: @Albert: welcome! This expression basically computes the minimum value of fecha_registro for records having tipo_acceso = A.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UNION`

```
SELECT accesslogs.login, usuarios.login, usuarios.nombre, 
    usuarios.apellido, COUNT(*)
FROM accesslogs 
  LEFT JOIN usuarios ON accesslogs.login = usuarios.id_usuario
where accesslogs.id_campania=173 
and accesslogs.tipo_acceso='A' 
and usuarios.id_usuario != 6658
GROUP BY accesslogs.login 
ORDER BY usuarios.login ASC
UNION
SELECT accesslogs.login, usuarios.login, usuarios.nombre, 
    usuarios.apellido, min(accesslogs.fecha_registro) 
FROM accesslogs 
  LEFT JOIN usuarios
  ON accesslogs.login = usuarios.id_usuario
where accesslogs.id_campania=173 
and accesslogs.tipo_acceso='A' 
and usuarios.id_usuario != 6658
GROUP BY accesslogs.login 
ORDER BY usuarios.login ASC
UNION
SELECT accesslogs.login, usuarios.login, usuarios.nombre, 
    usuarios.apellido, COUNT(*) 
FROM accesslogs 
  LEFT JOIN usuarios ON accesslogs.login = usuarios.id_usuario
where accesslogs.id_campania=173 
and accesslogs.tipo_acceso='U' 
and usuarios.id_usuario != 6658
GROUP BY accesslogs.login 
ORDER BY usuarios.login ASC
```